Ubuntu 24.04 screen spit into 2 halves and can't be undone. How to undo this?
Issue on Ubuntu 24.04.1 desktop.
When moving the psensor GUI to the middle of the top edge of one of the screen, that screen somehow split into 2 halves causing psensor to occupy the top half while the bottom half turned dark and shows three .desktop icons of apps that are opened. Thereafter, I revert the psensor GUI to its original size. However the split screen still persisted. Furthermore the lower half screen .desktop icons are unresponsive. What is going on? How do I fix this issue?
Note, this issue only occurred in one screen of a workspace and did not affect other workspaces.


I recently installed CUDA toolkit via
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit

Today, I undid that via
sudo apt purge nvidia-cuda-toolkit

I also did
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-470

to allow the nvidia-smi command to work again. After rebooting the system, the above mentioned issue no longer occurs.
From the above outcome, I think there could have been some graphic conflict caused by using CUDA ver. 12 on a system using the old NVIDIA graphic card that is using suppose to use NVIDIA -driver-470.
